# Firebase Realtime Database automatically deletes empty database with custom rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm developing a desktop app with Firebase Realtime Database as my database solution.

My app has minimal database usage so far (will increase as I keep developing it further) and leaves the database empty most of the time at this stage.

The problem I'm facing is that I have already written my database rules inside the Firebase console, but when the database is left empty for a while (maybe a day) I lose all of my rules when I navigate to Database section in the Firebase Console and see the start page. I have to click on Create Database again and create the database with default rules.

After encountering this on a daily basis, I kept my rules in a JSON file and connected my project to Firebase through Firebase Tools to be able to deploy them from the terminal, but my question is why is this happening? It's a little bit inconvenient to pause during development and keep reapplying my rules over and over again.

Why does the Realtime Database keep resetting when I leave it empty for a day?

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I was hoping this would get the attention of @Frank van Puffelen who's a Firebase team member and active on this forum.

Comment: I am also a Firebase team member, and I still think you should contact support.

Comment: Just contacted the support.